# Error with uitable logical format

Tags: matlab, matlab-uitable

I am creating a uitable using GUIDE with 4 columns: 1st – Numeric, 2nd – Let Matlab choose, 
3rd – Text, Editable, 4th – Logical, Editable.

When I run my GUI and try to mark the Logical checkbox I get this error: Warning: Table data is not editable at this location. Please click for more information.

I have tried to solve the problem and failed. Therefore, how can I fix it? I wish to check or uncheck them (the default selection should be checked).

Thanks.

Comment: Are you able to manipulate other columns?

Comment: Yes. The 3rd column is editable

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the create function for your uitable:

```
set(yourUitableHandle, 'ColumnEditable', [0 1 1 1]);
```

If the problem persists, something in GUIDE is automatically changing that property for you. Likely on the Data section of property viewer for the uitable. Let me know if that doesn't fix it, and I'll give it another shot.

Comment: Hi,

I added as you recommended.

function genereateDataButton_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
.
.
.
.

set(handles.infoTable, 'data',myData );
set(handles.infoTable, 'ColumnEditable', [0 1 1 1]); 

I get: Error using set
ColumnEditable must be a logical or logical array

Any idea why?

Thanks.

Comment: Whoops, try [false true true true].

Comment: Thanks for the help but still it is not working. Warning: Table data is not editable at this location. Please click for more information. Any other ideas?